# "Error in validVersions[with(validVersions, order(hadoop, decreasing = TRUE)), : subscript out of bounds" when using spark_install

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, sparkr

When I use `spark_isntall("3.0")`, I get an error [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVgxT.png)

```
Error in validVersions[with(validVersions, order(hadoop, decreasing = TRUE)),  :    subscript out of bounds
```

1. I re-installed R and RStudio again, but it does' work
2. When I check `spark_available_versions()`, I get the following on my console:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem

> spark_install("2.3")

Error in validVersions[with(validVersions, order(hadoop, decreasing = TRUE)),  :
subscript out of bounds

So I manually installed Spark and good to go. Hopefully someone will have an answer to our issue.

Comment: Yes. 
I am not sticking to this function spark_install() again, and I indicated the spark_home installation path in the spark_connect() function just like
SPARK_HOME="c:/spark/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home=SPARK_HOME, then It works.
Thank you.